# IE9 Localstorage API clear function issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, local-storage

```
localStorage.clear() 
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
JsonSerializer.js, line 347 character 6
```

In IE9 localStorage is not clearing...

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not positive this is the case for you, IE9 does not support local storage if you are loading a local file in offline mode (ie if you are loading it as a `file:///` URL).

But then I don't think `window.localStorage` is defined at all. Try this:

```
if(window.localStorage) {
  localStorage.clear() 
} else {
  alert("localStorage is not available");
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to load it from local or in offline mode. window.localStorage object is available in IE9, but the issue is happening when try to call localStorage.clear method.

Comment: Hmmm. Then nothing looks wrong with your code to me. Are you positive that is where the error is. It complaining about syntax sometimes its actually on one of the lines before?

Comment: The issue has poped up from, IE9 cannot handle empty string for Eval function. 
eg:
var text = "";
eval('(' + text + ')');